# Can I play Gta 5 missions any time during the day?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I know when you start a GTA mission sometimes it pauses and makes it a new time of day. But can you do some missions any time during the day? Personally I like the light of day to main missions and night time to do side missions. BUT if GTA makes a mission a certain time of day I could care less when to start a mission. So do GTA missions have a set time that they start, like if I start a mission will it pause and switch to a certain time?

Comment: Why'd this get a -1? XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes a Story Mission changes the time, because some missions have a better feeling at a diffrent time.

But Side Missions are synchron with the time you are playing when you start the side mission.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. You can't. Unless your on PC and have a trainer that can change time of day.